# ATL project not compiling in C++ 20 standard in VS2019

Tags: c++, mfc, visual-studio-2019, c++20, atl

I created a sample ATL project and I need to use some C++ 20 features.

When changed the C++ language standard to C++ 20 in project properties, getting a compilation error in afxhtml.h

```
1>pch.cpp
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\atlmfc\include\afxhtml.h(547,33): error C2760: syntax error: unexpected token 'identifier', expected ';'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\atlmfc\include\afxhtml.h(1557): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'CHtmlEditCtrlBase<T>' being compiled
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\atlmfc\include\afxhtml.h(570,33): error C2760: syntax error: unexpected token 'identifier', expected ';'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\atlmfc\include\afxhtml.h(630,33): error C2760: syntax error: unexpected token 'identifier', expected ';'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\atlmfc\include\afxhtml.h(650,33): error C2760: syntax error: unexpected token 'identifier', expected ';'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\atlmfc\include\afxhtml.h(676,33): error C2760: syntax error: unexpected token 'identifier', expected ';'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\atlmfc\include\afxhtml.h(693,33): error C2760: syntax error: unexpected token 'identifier', expected ';'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\atlmfc\include\afxhtml.h(718,15): error C3861: 'CW2CW': identifier not found
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\atlmfc\include\afxhtml.h(718,22): message : 'CW2CW': function declaration must be available as none of the arguments depend on a template parameter
```

The same works fine in sample console application

Comment: afxhtml.h is more MFC than ATL. Please post a fully reproducible sample https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/afxhtmlh-failes-to-compile-in-permissive-mode/1603989

Comment: What project did you create? Does the problem exist in Visual Studio 2022?

Comment: I have added a /permissible option in compiler setting, it is compiling now

Comment: Do you  mean /permissive? Please consider answering it and accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It  will help others with same problem, Just a reminder :)

Comment: Yes it is /permissive option, my apologies I have misspelt it. I will change the status also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added a /permissive option in compiler setting, it is compiling now